# Finding my Picasaweb album using my email

Tags: privacy, picasa-web-albums

I just found out that if I type my email into Google I can match that mail with my picasaweb account, is there a way to stop this from happening? Nothing else of mine is visible this way, so I don't see why picasa should be an exception.

Comment: Do you have Google+ account?

Answer (score 1):

What you are speaking about is impossible - there is no way by typing your email address you got match to your Picasa Album. Are you sure that you were not loged in to Google or any of the Google Services from your own account or any other account to which you have shared the album? Are you sure that you have the privacy settings of the album set to **Only me** or **Private** (or whatever it is called).